# Organise files for multiple mini-games for Discord bot

Tags: discord.js, organization

**EDIT : (rewrite)**
So, I'm doing a mini-games bot for my discord server. I have already done a bot with multiples features and it was organize like that :
- My main was handling my events. I was checking where my event was called and according to the channel, I will run my corresponding file.js.
- I have my main folder, with inside, one folder with my commands, one with my "handler" (like members counting, and other autonomous things), and the last one with my images.

Do you think it's correct, bad, and what can I improve ?
Can you send me your idea or your point on vue on that.

I try to make my code better each time I code, and organization is one of the thing I want to improve.

I hope it's a much more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the handy DiscordJS Guide that covers this subject and maybe put a little more effort into your research next time: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files

Comment: This was not what I expected from my question. Maybe my explaination was very bad ...

Comment: @BoBsmil3Y based off of your explanation, that guide can show you how to make a command handler, or essentially your commands/events broken into multiple files. You can double it up so that you can have a folder with commands for minigame1 and minigame2 seperately.